# Heroku dyno crashed

Tags: python, веб-программирование, heroku

Есть веб приложение на питоне, точнее телеграмм бот. Хостится на heroku, на одном веб дино, который регулярно ломается. Иногда оно само исправляется, иногда приходится перезапускать. Из-за чего такое происходит и как это починить?
Логи с начала запуска:

2020-05-18T06:25:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hehenukee@gmail.com
2020-05-18T06:26:21.115438+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user hehenukee@gmail.com
2020-05-18T06:26:21.115438+00:00 app[api]: Deploy bd19b255 by user hehenukee@gmail.com
2020-05-18T06:26:22.437968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-18T06:26:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-18T06:27:27.768857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-18T06:27:29.134558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xkcdnukeebot.herokuapp.com request_id=4d3d4a55-0292-49ac-91b6-b8383f18e9b4 fwd="128.70.15.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-18T06:31:48.564755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-18T06:32:54.333581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

В Procfile написано:

web: python main.py

UPD: просто поменял web на worker, и в настройках сделал то же самое

Comment: Без стэктрейса и кода вам  для помощи надо не специалистов искать, а экстрасенсов

Comment: Логи добавил, какой код вставить не знаю, т.к. само приложение работает отлично и очень быстро, проблема именно в дино

Comment: Вот что логи пишут. 
`heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"`
Всё проверили из советов поисковика по запросу `H10 App crashed`?

Comment: Перезапустил все дино, вроде работает.

Comment: А нет, снова сломалось

Comment: 2020-05-18T06:31:48.564755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-18T06:32:54.333581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-18T06:54:51.893877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-18T06:55:56.547873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-18T06:57:11.123098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-18T06:58:16.459020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Comment: Ваше приложение падает из-за конкретной ошибки, указанной в логах. Я вам эту строчку выцепил. Поищите решение по ней конкретно. В интернете слишком много советов по её поводу, чтобы копировать это всё сюда в виде ответа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108165/discussion-between---and-smellyns).